# HIVE: testMapPlan1(org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver) Failed

Tags: maven, hive

[INFO] Hive Query Language ............................... FAILURE

Hive appears to have build correctly, however, the TestExecDriver failed:

Tests run: 8, Failures: 8, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 23.331 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ uname -a
Linux vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/hive$ mvn clean install -Phadoop-2,dist -X

...

```
  Tests run: 8, Failures: 8, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 23.331 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver
    testMapPlan1(org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver)  Time elapsed: 1.621 sec  <<< FAILURE!
    junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<true> but was:<false>
        at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)

    at junit.framework.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:287)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:67)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:147)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver.executePlan(TestExecDriver.java:478)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver.testMapPlan1(TestExecDriver.java:487)

testMapPlan2(org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver)  Time elapsed: 0.828 sec  <<< FAILURE!
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<true> but was:<false>
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
    at junit.framework.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:287)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:67)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:147)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver.executePlan(TestExecDriver.java:478)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver.testMapPlan2(TestExecDriver.java:495)

testMapRedPlan1(org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver)  Time elapsed: 0.853 sec  <<< FAILURE!
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<true> but was:<false>
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
    at junit.framework.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:287)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:67)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:147)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver.executePlan(TestExecDriver.java:478)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver.testMapRedPlan1(TestExecDriver.java:504)

testMapRedPlan2(org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver)  Time elapsed: 0.691 sec  <<< FAILURE!
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<true> but was:<false>
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
    at junit.framework.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:287)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:67)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:147)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver.executePlan(TestExecDriver.java:478)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver.testMapRedPlan2(TestExecDriver.java:513)

testMapRedPlan3(org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver)  Time elapsed: 0.788 sec  <<< FAILURE!
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<true> but was:<false>
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
    at junit.framework.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:287)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:67)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:147)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver.executePlan(TestExecDriver.java:478)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver.testMapRedPlan3(TestExecDriver.java:522)

testMapRedPlan4(org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver)  Time elapsed: 0.712 sec  <<< FAILURE!
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<true> but was:<false>
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
    at junit.framework.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:287)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:67)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:147)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver.executePlan(TestExecDriver.java:478)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver.testMapRedPlan4(TestExecDriver.java:531)

testMapRedPlan5(org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver)  Time elapsed: 0.676 sec  <<< FAILURE!
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<true> but was:<false>
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
    at junit.framework.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:287)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:67)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:147)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver.executePlan(TestExecDriver.java:478)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver.testMapRedPlan5(TestExecDriver.java:540)

testMapRedPlan6(org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver)  Time elapsed: 0.748 sec  <<< FAILURE!
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<true> but was:<false>
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
    at junit.framework.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:287)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:67)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:147)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver.executePlan(TestExecDriver.java:478)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TestExecDriver.testMapRedPlan6(TestExecDriver.java:549)

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) on project hive-exec: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/vagrant/hive/ql/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) on project hive-exec: There are test failures.

Please refer to /home/vagrant/hive/ql/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There are test failures.

Please refer to /home/vagrant/hive/ql/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution(SurefireHelper.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary(SurefirePlugin.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:852)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:720)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem today, and I find that `-DskipTests` should be used when first compiling hive, such as

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

then run a `mvn install` can pass the test.